# (Python 2.7.6) I want to run an iteration that outputs less items each turn. How would I go about this?

Tags: python

I have a code where I have cities and distances and want to output them like a distance grid in an atlas(zeroes or no distance for distances with 0 or already calculated)

right now, I have:

```
def citydist():
    citymiles=" "
    for i in range(len(state)):
        citymiles=citymiles+"{0:^16.3f}".format(Miles[i])
    print citymiles
```

I want to run something under citymiles=citymiles.... that would output a row with one less item.  I can provide more if needed.

Comment: It's not clear what the questions is asking. Can you provide some intended input and desired output?

Comment: I am trying to get something like this http://d3svfn6as6o5bl.cloudfront.net/milecharter/tour/europetable_sq.png   without the distances left of the zeroes